# In PHP, I need to insert TLDs, 2LDs, etc into an array in order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a file with a list of domains, 2LDs, etc. I read it into an Array in PHP.
I have another list with domains which may be missing from the first list. I read this into another Array.
A cut-down version of the first array looks like this:

```
.com
.com.au
.tas.gov.au
.vic.gov.au
.wa.gov.au
.gov.au
.au
.co.uk

A sample from the second list to insert alphabetically:

.org.au
.wa.au
.sa.gov.au


So .org.au would have to be inserted after .gov.au
and .wa.au would have to be inserted after that.
and .sa.gov.au would need to be inserted before .tas.gov.au
```

I think I may have to explode the lists and make 2 different rules, one for each domain level (eg. .gov.au, .tas.gov.au) and process them separately. Then, depending on which number of levels it has, compare the left-most value in alphabetical order. (strcmp). Only, the values would have to be inserted above another lot of the same level values. (eg. **.org.au** does not go after **.com.au** and **.wa.au** does not go before **.wa.gov.au**)

Any ideas?

Could not post this without indenting random parts due to "Your post appears to contain code"

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand your sorting order. It seems like you sort them by each level in turn, right to left (resulting in a tree like structure), but I don't see why .com would go before all the *.au ?

Comment: Probably yes. .com may actually be after *.au  Good pickup. Just trying to put in an example. It's difficult to think how to insert them in the right place alphabetically, but retaining whether it's xxx.xxx or xxx.xxx.xxx and needs to end at .xx or .xxx

Comment: OK then I see two solutions. Simplest is storing domains reverted, then re-reverting for display.
Most efficient is storing them in a tree. I'll compose an answer as soon as I'm on a computer :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, so the way I see it, your best option is to store your domains in a reverse order, so that they sort alphabetically. The simplest way, imo (though not very efficient), is to simply have a big array with your domains reverted. so to insert you do smth like

```
$toAdd = join(".", array_reverse(explode(".", $domain)) . ".|";
array_push($allDomains, $toAdd);
array_sort($allDomains);
```

then to display a specific domain you need to re-revert it :

```
$domain = $allDomains[$i];
echo array_reverse(explode(".", str_replace($domain, ".|")));
```

This naïve implementation shoud work well enough for relatively small numbers of entries (say, a few thousands), barring any typo I made. I add `".|"` to the end of strings so that `.au.|` sorts after `.au.com.|`, if you don't care that root domains sort before their subs, just remove that part.

A more efficient way, I think, would be in a tree structure. the data would look like this :

```
'au' => array(
      'com' => true,
      'gov' = array(
          'tas' => true,
          'vic' => true,
          'was' => true,
          '|_ROOT' => true,
          [...]
```

Then, to insert a new domain you would navigate the tree, adding any new higher domain as an array, ant the "leaf" as a bool. You would sometimes need to replace a bool with a new array containing `'|_ROOT' => true`. Every time you add a key to an array, you `ksort`it. Again I use a `|` to sort root domains before their subs.

Displaying your domains should be a simple matter of walking the tree. If you need it I could propose you an implementation.